# Eject source file

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, tailwind-css

I have a Vue app (NodeJS, Webpack and TailwindCSS) and I want to use VSSUE commenting system. How to make custom style, the following is written:

https://vssue.js.org/guide/styles.html

```
Use Source Code of Vssue Styles

The style of Vssue is written in Stylus, and the source 
files are located in vssue/src/styles directory. 
The main style file is vssue/src/styles/index.styl.

You can eject and modify it to have fully customized styles for Vssue.
```

How to "eject" and then apply styling (with Tailwind?) or just a normal .css file? I have no clue what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs you provided, you have two options of modifying the default styles.

**Option 1**: Component generated by VSSUE is, in the end, a simple html - you can inspect the classes and override them with your global CSS. This is the simplest way - you can even omit the default css provided (just don't import `vssue.css`) and start styling from scratch. Of course you won't use Tailwind to do that, because you can not modify the existing classes.

**Option 2**: Modify the `stylus` variables to customize the look and feel, while preserving the default github style.

I believe that by `ejecting` the stylus file, the author wrote about a possibility of "copying and modifying as you wish" the original file. You don't need to do that - you can just tweak the variables. Here's how:

- You need `stylus` and `stylus-loader` installed in your dev-dependencies. If you use vue-cli, [thats all](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#pre-processors) - stylus will be supported right after installing these. For custom webpack config, add a [proper style loader to handle stylus files.](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html#stylus)
- Set the variables first, then import the main stylus file. Next,
  import the github-style css file. This is specified in the [docs](https://vssue.js.org/guide/styles.html#use-variables-to-customize-vssue) you provided.

Your code in Vue class component can look like

```
<style lang="stylus">
// set the variable first
$vssue-theme-color = red

// import the main file of Vssue styles and github-markdown-css
@import '~vssue/src/styles/index'
@import '~github-markdown-css/github-markdown.css'
</style>
```

Good luck!